# What is the advantage of @Autowired annotaion?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

In my spring example ,I declared two beans with following XML configuration file.

EmployeeBean.java

```
package autowire;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class EmployeeBean {
    private String fullName;  
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentBean departmentBean; 


    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public DepartmentBean getDepartmentBean() {
        return departmentBean;
    }


}
```

DepartmentBean.java

```
package autowire;

public class DepartmentBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="employee" class="autowire.EmployeeBean" autowire="byType">
      <property name="fullName" value="Charith"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="deptment" class="autowire.DepartmentBean">
      <property name="name" value="IT Department"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

TestAutowire .java

```
package autowire;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestAutowire {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring-servlet.xml"});

      EmployeeBean employee = (EmployeeBean)context.getBean("employee");
      System.out.println(employee.getFullName());
      System.out.println(employee.getDepartmentBean().getName());

    }

}
```

Above example is woking fine.After that I removed '@Autowired' annotation and add following lines to EmployeeBean.java

```
public void setDepartmentBean(DepartmentBean departmentBean) {
    this.departmentBean = departmentBean;
}
```

Now the example working fine with same output.My question is , What is the actual benefit when used '@Autowired' annotation?Because the code working fine without annotation but with setter method also.Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

`@AutoWired` can be useful as it saves you time writing "wiring" code. You don't have to call somewhere in your code the `setDepartment` method to init your object. Spring will do it for you.

In your case, see below how to accomplish this using annotations only. Note the use of `@Component` annotation for indicating auto scan components to Spring. Also note that no XML file is now needed.

**EmployeeBean.java**

```
package autowire;

/* Imports go here ... */

@Component
public class EmployeeBean {
    private String fullName;

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentBean departmentBean; 

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public DepartmentBean getDepartmentBean() {
        return departmentBean;
    }   
}
```

**DepartmentBean.java**

```
package autowire;

/* Imports go here ... */

@Component
public class DepartmentBean {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**TestAutowire .java**

```
package autowire;

/* Imports go here ... */

public class TestAutowire {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
      context.scan("autowire");
      context.refresh();

      EmployeeBean employee = (EmployeeBean)context.getBean("employee");
      System.out.println(employee.getFullName());
      System.out.println(employee.getDepartmentBean().getName());
    }
}
```

References:

- [Spring 3.2.x: Java Based container configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)